# Gulp Complies Sass even there exist lint errors

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have used `gulp-sass-lint` before the **scss** file get compiled to **css**. The Problem I am facing here is that scss is getting compiled to css even if there exist linting errors in scss.

How can i stop scss compiling to css if there are linting errors.

[image: This is My Folder Structure]

This is my gulpfile.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sassLint = require('gulp-sass-lint');

// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass-lint'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });
    gulp.watch("app/scss/*.scss", ['sass-lint']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("app/js/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// sass-lint check
gulp.task('sass-lint', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.s+(a|c)ss')
    .pipe(sassLint())
    .pipe(sassLint.format())
    .pipe(sassLint.failOnError())
    .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix:'.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "gulpscss_starterkit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "gulp"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.22.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sass-lint": "^1.3.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put sassLint into its own task.

```
// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

...

// sass
gulp.task('sass', ['sass-lint'], function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.s+(a|c)ss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(rename({
        suffix:'.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// sass-lint check
gulp.task('sass-lint', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.s+(a|c)ss')
    .pipe(sassLint())
    .pipe(sassLint.format())
    .pipe(sassLint.failOnError())
});
```